# Overfull warning when using longtable

Tags: spacing, longtable, warnings

I am getting overfull warning (`Overfull \hbox (17.10379pt too wide) in alignment`) when using `longtable` enviroment (See MWE below) The warnings are on `\begin{longtable}` and `\end* lines`. The pdf filellooks fine, but I would like to get rid of the warning message. Any suggestions on how to get rid of those warning by formatting the table?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{*2{p{0.49\textwidth}}}
        Title & Column 2 \\
        \hline
    \endfirsthead
        Title & Column 2 \\
        \hline
    \endhead
        \multicolumn{2}{r}{Continued}\\
    \endfoot
        \hline
    \endlastfoot

    \lipsum[1] & \lipsum[2]\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. Load the package `showframe` and you will see the problem. The width of a column is `.49\textwidth` but you forgot the `tabcolsep` on the left and right of every column.

Comment: thank you. I did not konw about showframe. I fixed the column width and now it works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not taking correctly into account the `\tabcolsep`, a space that is added in front and after all columns:

```
\begin{longtable}{*2{p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}}
```

Or, with the `calc` package,

```
\begin{longtable}{*2{p{0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}}
```